# SQL Server : select multiple item code where date is max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table there have so many item code, then i select '09015','09002','09025','09026' these item code, where pat_no = '33516', the problem is how can i compare the max rpt_time from these item code??

Here is my T-SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    [pat_no],[item_code],[value],[rpt_time]
FROM 
    [Tmhtc_PHR].[dbo].[lab_item] 
WHERE 
    [pat_no] = '33561' 
    AND ([item_code] = '09015' OR [item_code] = '09002' OR [item_code] = '09025' OR [item_code] = '09026')
ORDER BY 
    [rpt_time] DESC
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result? What do you mean when you say `compare the max rpt_time`? Or do you want to get only records with max `rpt_time` for each `item_code`?

Comment: hi yes, i want to get only records with max rpt_time for each item_code, how can i do that??
my expected result is:

pat_no   item_code     value        rpt_time
--------------------------------------------------------
33516       09026       23.000     2018-05-01
33516       09025       66.000     2018-05-01
33516       09015       5.500       2018-05-01
33516       09002       77.900     2018-05-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of two queries below:

```
SELECT  
    pat_no, item_code, [value], rpt_time
FROM Tmhtc_PHR.dbo.lab_item 
WHERE pat_no, item_code, rpt_time IN (
        SELECT pat_no, item_code, MAX(rpt_time)
        FROM Tmhtc_PHR.dbo.lab_item 
        WHERE pat_no = '33561' 
            AND item_code IN ('09015', '09002', '09025', '09026')
        GROUP BY item_code
    )
ORDER BY pat_no, item_code;
```

Or

```
SELECT  
    i.pat_no, i.item_code, i.[value], i.rpt_time
FROM Tmhtc_PHR.dbo.lab_item i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pat_no, item_code, MAX(rpt_time) AS max_rpt_time
    FROM Tmhtc_PHR.dbo.lab_item 
    WHERE pat_no = '33561' 
        AND item_code IN ('09015', '09002', '09025', '09026')
    GROUP BY item_code
) im
ON i.pat_no = im.i.pat_no AND i.item_code = im.item_code AND i.rpt_time = im.max_rpt_time
ORDER BY i.pat_no, i.item_code;
```